# DataBase em modo "Restoring"

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa tarde, a todos!

No SQL Server 2008, eu precisava fazer uma conversão no banco de dados de um dos nossos clientes e estava indo fazer o backup para caso ocorresse algum problema, só que erroneamente apertei para fazer um restore e por desatenção dei "Ok", no exato momento que apertei o botão reparei que estava fazendo restore e apertei a ação "Stop Action Now" ele parou e deu uma mensagem dizendo que o usuário tinha cancelado a ação. Até ai tudo bem, só que quando fui fazer o backup realmente ele não deixou dizendo que já existia uma restauração para esse banco de dados e quando vi o BD estava em modo "Restoring". Eu pesquisei na internet e vi que era para executar a seguinte query: RESTORE DATABASE NomeDatabase WITH RECOVERY

Mas antes de executar perguntei ao meu chefe se podia rodar essa query lá e ele falou que não era para fazer pois restauraria para o backup mais recente (e o mais recente é do dia 23/08). Sendo assim só temos o arquivo MDF e LDF do cliente, mas quando tentamos fazer um attach ele dá o seguinte erro:

> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Não foi possível abrir o novo
>   banco de dados 'DadosXXX'. CREATE DATABASE foi anulado. Msg 9004,
>   Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Erro ao processar o log para o banco de
>   dados 'DadosXXX'.  Se for possível, restaure a partir do backup. Se
>   não houver um backup disponível, pode ser necessário recriar o log.

Pesquisei esse erro no google também e vi que é necessário recriar o log mas ninguém aqui na empresa tem esse conhecimento. Gostaria de saber se alguém aqui já passou por essa situação tem algum conhecimento para poder ajudar.

Grato desde já.

Comment: Esse restore que você fez por engano foi de que tipo? Pois inclusive é possível fazer o restore para um "momento" do tempo, quando se tem um backup full + um arquivo de Log

Comment: Olá! Segue a imagem: https://i.imgur.com/eOwWS41.png

Comment: Tente fazer um novo restore, para uma nova base, para não perder os dados da base atual. E no campo "to a point in time", clique no botão "..." e veja quais as opções que o log te dá, na nova janela, veja qual é o ponto mais recente no tempo que a base de dados consegue ser restaurada.

Comment: Então.. Ai que temos um problema, meu chefe fez um detach nessa base que deu problema, e depois excluiu para tentar fazer um restore pelo MDF. Será que eu consigo fazer mesmo assim?

Comment: Aí acho que não. Pois não conseguiu atachar novamente não é?

Comment: Não, sempre que tentava fazer o attach dava o erro que está quotado ali em cima :/